# Fredholm integral equation of first kind

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, analysis, numerical-methods

I want to solve the Fredholm integral equation of first kind: $$ \int_L K(x,y)U(y)dy = f(x) $$ in these equation the function $U(y)$ is the unknown and the so-called kernel $K$ and the right hand side $f$ are given functions. I've used the set of orthogonal functions $\phi_i(x)$ i.e., $$\langle \phi_i,\phi_j \rangle = \left\{\begin{array}{c} 0 \ i\neq j \\ 1 \ i=j \end{array}\right. $$  and approximate the $f(x)$,$K(x,y)$ and $U(y)$ by these set functions.$$f(x)=\sum_i\alpha_i \phi_i \text{ where } \alpha_i= \langle f(x),\phi_i \rangle, \text{ and } U(y)=\sum_i\beta_i \phi_i \\K(x,y)=\sum_i\sum_j\omega_{i,j} \phi_i(x) \phi_j(y)$$ Now by substitution of these approximate into main equation and using the property of orthogonality, I obtained a linear equation in this form $A \beta=\alpha$, where $ \alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_n)^T$, $\beta=(\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_n)^T$ and $A=[\omega_{i,j}]$ but the determinant of $A$ matrix is zero and I can't solve the equation. What happened in this method?

Comment: Could you tell what the kernel $K(x,y)$ is?

Answer (score 5):

In general, Fredholm integral equation of first kind arise typically with a compact operator in applications and hence can be notoriously conditioned when solving numerically. Also, sometimes the kernel $K$ can in fact be a finite rank operator, in which case you cannot even solve it analytically, let alone numerically. This is one reason why people work with integral equations of the second kind, since they tend to be better conditioned than their first kind counterparts.

Comment: any kernel that i test it for example sin(xy) or x+y and i use daubechies scale function for set of orthogonal function

Comment: @sorush $x+y$ is a kernel of rank $2$. So no wonder the matrix has determinant $0$. $\sin(xy)$ is a compact operator and the determinant will be very close to zero.

Comment: this mean that i cannot solve this problem by this way

Comment: @sorush It means you cannot solve the problem by any way. The kernel is a low-rank matrix and you cannot invert a low-rank matrix.

Comment: but for example the answer of this equation $$(sin(x) - x*cos x)/x^2=\int_0^1sin(xy)u(y)dy$$ is u(y)=y;and in many research article   solve it by this method(for example using chebyshev wavelet)

Comment: @sorush You should not solve it numerically. The associated matrix will be very ill-conditioned. Lot of people do it, but this is not the right way to do it numerically, as you have seen in your case.

Answer (score 1):

When the kernel is Wiener-Hopf (depending on just x - y, as in many cases in physics), you can find a seemingly explicit solution.
Of course, in general, it is not a question of choice to deal with a second order type rather, or, what is even more convenient, choose a Volterra type one.
But these are much more friendly.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how does this answers the OP's question. This seems more like a comment on how these problems in general can be difficult, not on why this particular case is unsolvable using the OP's method.